# block / unblock Calls. Differencing between incoming / outgoing

Tags: android, callblocking

I'm trying to control calls from my App.

Thanks to this post [Blocking Incoming call](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html) -  [Call Control in Android](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com.es/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html) -[Question Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083527/how-to-block-calls-in-android) And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971524/how-to-resolve-this-error-com-android-internal-telephony-cannot-be-resolved-to) .  I was able cancel incoming/outgoing calls

I register the ITelephony class (com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony),

defined a receiver in the Manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".PhoneCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And in PhoneCallReceiver I override the OnRecive Method, using reflection to instance ITelephony.

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Receving....");
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
        //telephonyService.silenceRinger();
        if (!(InfoAct.ismodguiaon(context))){
            telephonyService.endCall();
        } else {

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This works, but I want to make differences between incoming and outgoing calls and I don't know how. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In manifest,Receiver tag action 
for outgoing call,

refer [this](http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/)