# issue with TelephonyManager, classNotFoundException

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am trying to create an app that can block an incoming call. I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` for `TelephonyManager`.Following is the code I am using. What is that I am doing wrong here?

BroadcastReceiver

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class TelephoneBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String TAG = "My Tag";
    String incomingNumber = "";
    String incno1 = "5556";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d(TAG, "INF: Broadcast received.");

        try{

            TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Log.v(TAG, "Get getTeleService...");    
            Class c = Class.forName(tManager.getClass().getSimpleName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tManager);
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            incomingNumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.v(TAG,incomingNumber );
            Log.v(TAG,incno1 );
            if ( incomingNumber.equals(incno1) ) {
                 telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tManager);
                 telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                 telephonyService.endCall();
                 Log.v(TAG,"BYE BYE BYE" );
            }
            else{
                telephonyService.answerRingingCall();
                Log.v(TAG,"HELLO HELLO HELLO" );
            }           
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG,
                    "FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception object: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest File

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.atiffarrukh.callandsmsfilter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name="com.atiffarrukh.callandsmsfilter.broadcastreceiver.TelephoneBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter  >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now the Error

```
08-02 13:21:20.641: D/My Tag(557): INF: Broadcast received.
08-02 13:21:20.641: V/My Tag(557): Get getTeleService...
08-02 13:21:20.641: W/System.err(557): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TelephonyManager
08-02 13:21:20.641: W/System.err(557):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-02 13:21:20.641: W/System.err(557):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:235)
08-02 13:21:20.641: W/System.err(557):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:182)
08-02 13:21:20.641: W/System.err(557):  at com.atiffarrukh.callandsmsfilter.broadcastreceiver.TelephoneBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(TelephoneBroadcastReceiver.java:30)
08-02 13:21:20.641: W/System.err(557):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
08-02 13:21:20.641: W/System.err(557):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-02 13:21:20.641: W/System.err(557):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
08-02 13:21:20.641: W/System.err(557):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 13:21:20.641: W/System.err(557):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TelephonyManager
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557):  ... 15 more
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TelephonyManager in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.atiffarrukh.callandsmsfilter-1.apk]
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
08-02 13:21:20.764: W/System.err(557):  ... 15 more
08-02 13:21:20.764: E/My Tag(557): FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem
08-02 13:21:20.764: E/My Tag(557): Exception object: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TelephonyManager
```

**Thanks...**

Comment: Refer this link,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971524/how-to-resolve-this-error-com-android-internal-telephony-cannot-be-resolved-to

Comment: I have already added the .AIDL  file in the exact `com.android.internal.telephony` package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
Class c = Class.forName(tManager.getClass().getName());
```

Instead of getSimpleName() see below link

http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/