# Android Reflection confusion

Tags: android, reflection

I'm trying to reflect an Android class, we know it can be done because of other applications doing it but struggling to achieve the result ourselves.

We're stuck at the below

```
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("android.content.pm.PackageManager");
Method method = myClass.getMethod("deleteApplicationCacheFiles", String.class,IPackageDataObserver.class);
```

IPackageDataObserver.class doesn't exist

```
import android.content.pm.IPackageDataObserver;
```

Also doesn't work, I can manually get the code for the interfaces from Google and put them into the Package but that seems a little OTT, wondering if i'm missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

Add the IPackageDataObserver class to the project your self, its the only way to do this.

make a package in you source folder naming it "android.content.pm" and add this class to it, this class is just original android source code:

```
/*
 * This file is auto-generated.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 * Original file: frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/IPackageDataObserver.aidl
 */
package android.content.pm;
/**
 * API for package data change related callbacks from the Package Manager.
 * Some usage scenarios include deletion of cache directory, generate
 * statistics related to code, data, cache usage(TODO)
 * {@hide}
 */
public interface IPackageDataObserver extends android.os.IInterface
{
/** Local-side IPC implementation stub class. */
public static abstract class Stub extends android.os.Binder implements android.content.pm.IPackageDataObserver
{
private static final java.lang.String DESCRIPTOR = "android.content.pm.IPackageDataObserver";
/** Construct the stub at attach it to the interface. */
public Stub()
{
this.attachInterface(this, DESCRIPTOR);
}
/**
 * Cast an IBinder object into an android.content.pm.IPackageDataObserver interface,
 * generating a proxy if needed.
 */
public static android.content.pm.IPackageDataObserver asInterface(android.os.IBinder obj)
{
if ((obj==null)) {
return null;
}
android.os.IInterface iin = (android.os.IInterface)obj.queryLocalInterface(DESCRIPTOR);
if (((iin!=null)&&(iin instanceof android.content.pm.IPackageDataObserver))) {
return ((android.content.pm.IPackageDataObserver)iin);
}
return new android.content.pm.IPackageDataObserver.Stub.Proxy(obj);
}
public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
{
return this;
}
@Override public boolean onTransact(int code, android.os.Parcel data, android.os.Parcel reply, int flags) throws android.os.RemoteException
{
switch (code)
{
case INTERFACE_TRANSACTION:
{
reply.writeString(DESCRIPTOR);
return true;
}
case TRANSACTION_onRemoveCompleted:
{
data.enforceInterface(DESCRIPTOR);
java.lang.String _arg0;
_arg0 = data.readString();
boolean _arg1;
_arg1 = (0!=data.readInt());
this.onRemoveCompleted(_arg0, _arg1);
return true;
}
}
return super.onTransact(code, data, reply, flags);
}
private static class Proxy implements android.content.pm.IPackageDataObserver
{
private android.os.IBinder mRemote;
Proxy(android.os.IBinder remote)
{
mRemote = remote;
}
public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
{
return mRemote;
}
public java.lang.String getInterfaceDescriptor()
{
return DESCRIPTOR;
}
public void onRemoveCompleted(java.lang.String packageName, boolean succeeded) throws android.os.RemoteException
{
android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
try {
_data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR);
_data.writeString(packageName);
_data.writeInt(((succeeded)?(1):(0)));
mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_onRemoveCompleted, _data, null, android.os.IBinder.FLAG_ONEWAY);
}
finally {
_data.recycle();
}
}
}
static final int TRANSACTION_onRemoveCompleted = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 0);
}
public void onRemoveCompleted(java.lang.String packageName, boolean succeeded) throws android.os.RemoteException;
}
```

Rolf

Answer (score 1):

This question has 1 year, but I like complete it with some useful information, other solution it's add to your project the lib layoutlib.jar that is in plaform//data and compile as provided (this is not include on your binary), on this way your project can resolve the dependency, because this clases are not on the public sdk.

Comment: how can i add layoutlib.jar file ??

Comment: you can find layoutlib on plaform/android-<version>/data/ . If you are using gradle, put the jar on your libs folder and add the dependency on the build.xml the line provided files('libs/layoutlib.jar')

Comment: i m using eclipse and i have added layoutlib.jar but still this code is returning me package name null in  onRemoveComplete override method

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `IPackageDataObserver` is original `AIDL` file so it generate at runtime in `gen` folder not `src` folder. So solution is add `IPackageDataObserver.aidl` to your project and remember to keep this file up-to-date. You can get content of [IPackageDataObserver](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/pm/IPackageDataObserver.aidl).

```
/*
**
** Copyright 2007, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
** You may obtain a copy of the License at
**
** http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
** limitations under the License.
*/

package android.content.pm;

/**
 * API for package data change related callbacks from the Package Manager.
 * Some usage scenarios include deletion of cache directory, generate
 * statistics related to code, data, cache usage(TODO)
 * {@hide}
 */
oneway interface IPackageDataObserver {
    void onRemoveCompleted(in String packageName, boolean succeeded);
}
```

Another similar SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9971524/1050058)