# unable to import file to a project class in Android Studio

Tags: android, class

im new to Android Studio (v 0.3.7) and trying to follow the explanation in the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971524/how-to-resolve-this-error-com-android-internal-telephony-cannot-be-resolved-to#comment30509298_9971524)

I added a folder structure "com/android/internal/telephony" and in it the ITelephony.AIDL file  to my project "MyApplication3".

like this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-15\MyApplication3\com\android\internal\telephony\ITelephony.AIDL"

but when trying to add the line

```
import com.android.internal.telephony
```

to the class in this file

```
PhoneCallStateListener.java
```

the editor marks telephony as red, also when using the editor import structure autocomplete, the new folder structure doesn't show. am i adding the folder structure in the right place ?

Thanks

Comment: could it be that simple ? or that difficult ?

Answer (score 0):

By default Android Studio requires AIDL files to be in aidl folder. Just create a new folder src/main/aidl/ and put this aidl file to correct folder. in your case it will be com/android/internal/telephony/ Take a look at folder /build/source/aidl/debug... in order to ensure that Android Studio compiles aidl files.