# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol ITelephony

Tags: java, android, call, block

I'm working on an Android app that is supposed to block incoming calls and (eventually) messages. So far I've read that you can use the internal ITelephony interface to intercept and eventually block calls.

One step of that process involves creating a package called "com.android.internal.telephony" containing a "ITelephony.aidl" file. I've got the following path right now:

\MyApp\app\src\main\java\company\MyApp\com\android\internal\telephony\ITelephony.aidl (this is what Android Studio creates with the "Create Package" command.

The issue is that, for some reason, I get the following error:

error: package com.android.internal.telephony does not exist. I've tried placing the aidl file in different locations but with the same result. Am I doing something wrong and, if so, how do I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution to your problem:

> you have added `ITelephony.AIDL` file in your project? and if you have added then your package name must be
>   `com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.AIDL`: for more information
>   [Blocking Incoming call](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/). download AIDL file from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java)

From: [how to resolve this error "com.android.internal.telephony cannot be resolved to a type" in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971524/how-to-resolve-this-error-com-android-internal-telephony-cannot-be-resolved-to)

Shortly: make `com/android/internal/telephony` folder structure inside src folder and put `aidl` file in telephony folder.

So you telephony package may has wrong directory structure.

Please check and try to follow steps above.

Comment: I created the specified structure but the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Please use complete path of COM package that contain the interface ITelephony.

**Example**

If you are using

```
ITelephony telephonyService =(ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
```

Then you should use

```
com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
```